# How do you watch a variable in xcode 4?

Tags: debugging, xcode4

How do you watch a variable in xcode 4? I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is the expression window in Xcode 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632477/where-is-the-expression-window-in-xcode-4) Just enter the variable name as expression.

Comment: thanks my question is a dupe.

Comment: same question here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500718/does-xcode4-have-a-watch-window

Answer (score 13):

Right click in the local variables window to see the "Watch Expression" menu command. Type the variable name and the variable will be added.

Comment: Where is this "watch expression" menu?

Answer (score 3):

"Watch VariableName" is available in debug area. Just right click on a var and select "Watch var".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 ways to watch a variable and break at certain condition.

1. Edit breakpoints

Control-click a breakpoint indicator to display a command menu and choose Edit Breakpoint to open the breakpoint editor and set conditions, add actions, and so forth, as mentioned in Breakpoints.
[image]

2. Use LLDB command line. For example, below command will watch the value of 'I', and break when I==3.

   (lldb) watch set var i
   Watchpoint created: Watchpoint 1: addr = 0x100001018 size = 4 state = enabled type = w
       declare @ '/Volumes/data/lldb/svn/ToT/test/functionalities/watchpoint/watchpoint_commands/condition/main.cpp:12'
   (lldb) watch modify -c 'i==3'
   (lldb) watch list

This is where you can type LLDB command in Xcode.

[image]