# Does Xcode have a watch window?

Tags: xcode, debugging, global-variables

Does Xcode have a watch window for variables? It has a window for local variables but that's not much help when I want to watch the value of a global.

I've been spoiled by VisualStudio, I know.

Comment: Hey Chris.  I assume you are still developing in XCode.  Is this still available in XCode 4.2.  I'm new to XCode development and I can't find this or how to use your self-posted solution.

Comment: It's available in Xcode 4.4 but (I think) not before that. And it doesn't seem to work as expected in 4.4 (unless my expectation is wrong).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you watch a variable in xcode 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982230/how-do-you-watch-a-variable-in-xcode-4)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Solved! Right-clicking in the local variables window brings a menu option of "Add Expression". Type your variable name and now you are watching your variable/expression.

The language of "expression" instead of the more familiar "variable" threw me quite a bit. Hard to search for a solution when I have the terminology wrong. Seems obvious now.

Answer (score 7):

**Xcode Expression window**

Open Debug Area via `View -> Debug Area -> Activate Console` (Xcode 9)

`Right click -> Add Expression`

[image]