# NSLog Alternatives?

Tags: objective-c, ios

**Original question:**
What are the alternative logging modules to NSLog for an iOS application? Please explain the pros and cons that you've experienced first hand.

**Additional request 1:**
I did try to use the TestFlight TFLog which also helps with uploading the logs to their server but it seems to be limited when you need logging when app is running in the background. A logging system that helps with rolling/compressing the log files and server uploads would greatly help.

**Additional request 2:**
Another issue of NSLog that some have written about is that Apple does not like it when you submit the app for production.

Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you told us what you wish was different about NSLog.

Comment: Sosborn, I just added some more info but I am also hopping to hear about some important features that I might not yet be aware of. thanks.

Comment: I see, after the question was completely edited someone went through most of the answers down-voting w/o any comment. Santa, no Christmas present to that person, please, as well as to the Edit approver.

Comment: You can use a breakpoint and actual debugging.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's always the `printf` family of functions, those are generally faster than `NSLog`, but do not have support for the `%@` format specifier for objects.

Lately I've been using the excellent [Lumberjack](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack) framework for logging, which is asynchronous and will not have a performance impact on your code. It also has tons of customization features for log output formatting.

Comment: This seems very interesting. I will definitely take a shot at using this. Thanks.

Comment: Lumberjack is really good. If u want some different log framwork that have a look at https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger

Answer (score 3):

If you're interested in making your own NSLog variant (a complete replacement), have a look [here](http://www.karlkraft.com/index.php/2009/03/23/114/).

If you don't want to make your own NSLog but would rather customise what the current NSLog can have a look at some of the tricks outlined [on this page instead](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/tutorial-discussion/68451-tutorial-customising-the-nslog-function.html).

Personally, I prefer the redo-NSLog-from-scratch approach as it offers much more control. It does however take quite a bit more time to implement and you have to learn about variable argument lists and their implementation in order to get it working properly. This becomes particularly painful when you want to pass va_lists around to different functions. One handy feature of making your own version is that you can setup functions to log to wherever you like (the console, or different log files) - it all comes back to smart `fprintf` calls at the end of the day.

On the other hand if you just want to customise NSLog in-place, then really all you need to do is become familiar with a few handy compiler macros (such as `__LINE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, etc). This is the easier approach, and may be all that you're after, but it doesn't provide as much control as rolling your own.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

you may already know that, but you can always watch variables values when debugging in XCode

check out this
[Does Xcode have a watch window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500718/does-xcode4-have-a-watch-window)

Answer (score 1):

The best alternative I know is a macros, you can use it with any predefined C macro `__FILE__`, `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, etc.

**Prototype**

```
#define MyLog(args...) MyLogImpl(__FILE__,__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,args);

void MyLogImpl(const char *filename, const char *funcPrettyName, NSString *formatStr, ...);
```

**Implementation**

With `va_start() va_end()` you'll be able to get the format. In order to compensate `printf` lack of format support you are going to use this values as following:

```
NSString *messageStr =  [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:formatStr arguments:replacingArgumentParameters];
```

And then you are able to print the standard message together with any other data, like

```
fprintf(stderr, "%s %s", filename, messageStr);
```

which gives you not only the message itself but also the file name was calling the MYLog.

Another useful trick is to limit the messages to the current log_level or running configuration.

If you feel  yourself experienced enough you could also go ahead and try to redefine the standard NSLog macros.

Answer (score 0):

As "A-Live" said the best alternative is a Macro. Just define following MACRO in your .pch file.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
   #define debug(format, ...) CFShow((__bridge void *)[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s [LINE: %d] ==>> " format,__PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ## __VA_ARGS__]);
#else
#endif
```

Now, How to use the above Macro ?

**Sample**

```
debug(@"Version Number is 1.0");
```

Note:

You can disable all ***debug logs*** by Editing your schema. 
Under the Edit Schema select first Tab i.e. "**Info**"

In "Info" tab set Build Configuration to "Release" and press "OK" button.

[image]