# How check global vars in debugger of Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4.2

In Xcode 3.2 it was possible to check global vars in the Xcode debugger (by defining interesting vars in a special dialog).

However in Xcode 4.2 I can't find a way to inspect global vars.

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632477/where-is-the-expression-window-in-xcode-4

Answer (score 4):

1) Open the debugger drawer thingy

2) Show the Variables view (the left section), or both the Variables view and the Console

3) On the header of the variables view, there is a popup on the left - choose "All variables, registers, statics, globals"

Comment: Thank you Justin, your answer is correct so far, but the "missing link" was in the previous comment by madmw: So step 4) to your answer should be: context-click in the debugger window to select "Add expression..." in the pop-up-menu and enter the name of the global variable in the upcomming window. Anyway thanx for your help.

Comment: Step4)Right click in the debugger window shows the pop-up menu. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a little-known feature in Xcode that's been available for more than a decade. Suspend the app's process and right-click the variables view. Choose **Add Expression...** from the contextual menu and enter the expression that returns the global variable, for example, a singleton. The global variable should then be listed in the variables view.

What I like about this feature is that Xcode remembers the expressions you enter across debug sessions. You don't need to add the same expression every time you run and debug your app. To remove a global variable, right-click the expression and choose **Delete Expression**. [This tutorial](https://cocoacasts.com/how-to-inspect-global-variables-in-xcode-debugger) provides an in-depth look at this feature.